# guys i have so much trouble trying to make this work the itemconfig is not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import time
class game:
    def __init__(self,widthh,heighht):

        self.tk=Tk()
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.tk, width=widthh, height=heighht )
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.background=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/ryantan/Desktop/python/run for your life/player sprite/player1.gif")
        self.over=self.canvas.create_image(200,200,image = self.background, anchor = 'center')
        self.tk.update()

    def mainloop(self):
        while True:
            self.tk.update()
g=game(1000,400)
g.canvas.itemconfig(g.over,image = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/ryantan/Desktop/python/run for your life/player sprite/player2.gif"))
g.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, @ryan.  Welcome to SO. Could you please provide the error message?

Comment: there was no error message...

Comment: the program just ran and it didnt display anything

Comment: there was no error message

Comment: why did you define your own `mainloop`? The way you implemented it does the same as the built-in `mainloop`, but considerably less efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you don't keep a reference to the image created within the `itemconfig`. The garbage colector needs to know you want to keep this object. You can check the documentation [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method).

I've removed your update loop as this is not necessary. `Tk.mainloop()` will handle that for you.

```
from tkinter import *


class Game:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=width, height=height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.background = PhotoImage(
            file="C:/Users/ryantan/Desktop/python/run for your life/player sprite/player1.gif"
        )
        self.over = self.canvas.create_image(
            200, 200, image=self.background, anchor='center'
        )

    def mainloop(self):
        self.tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Game(1000, 400)
    new_image = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/ryantan/Desktop/python/run for your life/player sprite/player2.gif")
    g.canvas.itemconfig(
        g.over,
        image=new_image
    )
    g.mainloop()
```